# When does $\frac{1}{2n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_{n-i+1}\right) \leq \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^2$?

Tags: inequality, rearrangement-inequality

From [brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chebyshev-inequality/), the Chebyshev's inequality, a generalization of the [rearrangement inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/), states that for every nonincreasing sequences $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^n$,

$$
 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i \geq \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i\right)
\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_{n-i+1}\,.
$$
As a special case when $a_i = b_i = x_i$, we have
$$
 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i \geq \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^2
\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_{n-i+1}\,.
$$
Clearly, knowing that $a\leq \frac{1}{2}(a+b)\leq b$,
$$
 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i 
\geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_{n-i+1}\right)
\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_{n-i+1}\,.
$$
**Question:** When does the following inequality hold?
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_{n-i+1}\right) \leq \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^2
$$

**UPDATE Remark:** This inequality does not hold in general but I am interested in the additional necessary restrictions on the $x_i$'s for the inequality to hold.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wrong.

Try, $n=5$, $x_1=1$ and $x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=0$.

Comment: Yes, I have observed that it does not generally hold. But my question is when does it hold?, i.e., what restrictions should we add to $x_i$'s for the inequality to necessary and/or sufficiently hold?